# How can I select an option in vue-multiselect in a dusk test?

Tags: vue.js, laravel-dusk

I am using laravel dusk to write tests in my application. In a form I use a vue-multiselect component. I haven't found out how to select an option in dusk.

Any pointers on this?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you still have that problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by click function

```
$browser->click('input.multiselect__input');
$browser->click('li.multiselect__element');
```

if you want to select specific option than you need to just set nth-of-type

```
$browser->click('li.multiselect__element:nth-of-type(2)');
```

Got Reference From : https://github.com/shentao/vue-multiselect/issues/315

Answer (score 1):

Had similar issue and ended up using the following:

On your multiselect component you will have to add the following slots

```
// this slot will open the multiselect, 
// you might get around this by targeting the id of the input
<template slot="caret"> 
   <div class="multiselect__select" dusk="select-tags"></div>
</template>
// this slot is important to target each option alone
<template slot="option" slot-scope="props">
   <span :dusk="props.option.name">{{ props.option.name }}</span>
</template>
```

This way you can target the multiselect and then select what you want based on the name or you could even use id or whatever you want.

```
$browser->click('@select-tags');
$browser->click('@firstTag');
```

inspired by this [post](https://github.com/shentao/vue-multiselect/issues/365)